# Is this approach safe to SQL Injections?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sql-injection, websecurity

I have the following code to retrieve data from my database in Express.js with MySQL queries. I used to develop on vanilla HTML, JS, PHP... Now I'm using React and Express.js for the Back End and these two languages are a new world to me. What I want to know is if making queries like this are a thing safe to do.

Much appreciated, thanks for the help.

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME
});

exports.sesion = async (req, res) => {

  console.log(req.body);

  try {   
    const { email, password } = req.body[0];

    if(!email || !password) {
      res.json({
        message: 'Por favor introduzca su email y contraseña'
      })
    }

    db.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = ?', [email], async (error, filas, fields) => {
      
      if(filas.length === 0) {
        res.json([
          {message: 'Los datos ingresados son incorrectos'}
        ])
      }
      else if(filas && !(await bcrypt.compare(password, filas[0].password))) {
        res.json([
          {message: 'Los datos ingresados son incorrectos'}
        ])
      }
      else {
        res.json([
          {message: 'Inicio de sesión correcto'}
        ])
      }
    })

  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Do consider checking on [security.se] for answers, and input, from folks with a focus on security concerns.

Comment: The above code is vulnerable to user enumeration via a timing attack, because the response time for existing and non-existing users is very different due to bcrypt only being run on one branch of the condition. But there is no SQLi. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is safe. You parameterized the user's input, so it's safe against SQL injection.

For even more safety you could validate the email from the user with one of those vast regexes designed for the purpose, like this one. https://emailregex.com/

Answer (score 1):

This should be safe since mysql package escapes it if passed as parameter. There are also more verbose ways to do that: You can see them here: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values.

````js
var userId = 'some user provided value';
var sql    = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ' + connection.escape(userId);
connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  // ...
});```
````